# Proving that $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n = F(n), n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$

Tags: continued-fractions, natural-numbers, square-numbers

Let $F(n)$ denote a infinite continued fraction of form such that:

$$F(n) = \cfrac{1}{2n + \cfrac{1}{2n + \cfrac{1}{2n + \cfrac{1}{2n + \cfrac{1}{\dots}}}}}$$

Consider the following equation:

$$\sqrt{n^2+1}-n = F(n), n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$$

Could this be easily proven?
It seems to be correct, but I have no idea where to start...

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you see anything in the continued fraction expression that can be substituted by $F(n)$?

Answer (score 8):

Hint:

Try $$F(n) = \frac{1}{2n + F(n)}$$

Comment: Sweet... Thanks... +1

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)